# Changing Scene in Pause Mode Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I currently have a Pause scene in which the animation is a closing door. (Added to the gameworld via add layer). If I choose resume, it will open up and resume the game.
I've also a Quit button in which player will go back to the game menu. I like the
effect to be when quit is selected the door will open to the game menu. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I created the same animation onto the game menu. So when I replace scene the animation will
be played from the game menu.